# linux permissions: group files edited by different users

Tags: linux, permissions, centos

I cant seem to figure out how to achieve my goal to make a solution so all users within a grou work with the same set of files freely.

I got a group "developers", and they are developing a project. Now do i got number of users:
`user1:developers, user2:developers, user3:developers` ... and etc.

Now they can create, run delete files in that project, but they can not save/edit files created by other users from the same project (`group`).

All files in the project got `770` permissions on them.

Is there a way to achieve this in CentOS Linux ?

Comment: What permissions do the folders have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use setgid and assign developers as the group owner of the folder, as follows:

```
chown nobody:developers /sharedfolder
```

Then,

```
chmod g+s /sharedfolder
```

Newly added files should now be read/write by all members of the developers group.  If you have existing data in the folder already you'll need to do the chmod recursively with the -R switch.

Comment: Hi, I have been testing this, but it does not seem to fully solve the problem. Now when some user in the group creates a directory, it does not have the Write permission. Any ideas how to go around that ?

Comment: another thing is that at the moment I keep putting 770 permisions on all the folders so people could work, but every time some1 edits some file or folder, entire directory becomes `drwxr-x---` again. It all started after I made those modifications. I tried `g-s` but it still made no difference.

Comment: It sounds like you need to adjust your default umask in /etc/bashrc. Using a value of 002 should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Check http://www.psc.edu/general/unix/umask.php or
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask

What you need is have your user profiles edited to have a different umask so that files they create get default permissions that allow group to edit them.